# Unable to switch task for Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, task-switching

I'm new to Visual Studio and C#. Just finished a Windows Form Application but detected following bugs. The program will dies (showing Not Responding) whenever user minimize/restores it, or switch to another task. This bug prevents user multitasking while running this program, so I really want to fix if.
I wonder what are the possible causes of the problem, and how to solve them in general. I'd really appreciate any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are maybe doing something in Control.LostFocus event handler that is locking the GUI.  Anything like that in your code that you can post?

Comment: I don't have any code regarding Control.LostFocus event handler. The program has nearly 2000 lines and I don't think posting a small portion of code would help. As Peter suggested below, I think giant loop is the main cause so far.

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything where you have a long running loop or long running operation in your `Form`.  The fact that you only see "not responding" when you minimize and restore is probably due to the fact that you've forced the window to redraw and forced Windows to recognize the app is hung and use the ghost window.  The window was probably already hung before you minimized and restore it.  You can verify this by trying to move the window. If it doesn't move, it's hung.  If it does move, try to move the title bar off-screen and back (e.g. click in the middle of the title bar and drag it all the way to the right and release the button, then do the same and bring it back on screen).

Comment: The program is hung when I tried to move the window. If you do not try to move or minimize the program, it just works fine.I agreed with you that it may caused by running a giant loop. But the program has to do so, by first iterating 100k+ lines file. Any possible causes other than the loop concern?

Comment: It just appears to work fine, the window is still hung.  If you switch to another app and back, you'll have similar "not responding" issues.  It could be a loop or some other lengthy operation, without seeing the code there's a infinite number of guesses. The only way to fix this is to find the lengthy operation and move it off the UI thread to another thread.  BackgroundWorker is useful for this.

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong you are running with a problem of UI freezing. if so why don't you use C# BackgroundWorker. it help you to prevent freezing the window form whether you doing a long task. you can find a good tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker here. Hope this will help.